# What happens to unreleased memory on the heap?

Tags: android, c++

If we miss to free any memory allocated on the heap, is that memory going to be unavailable for ever? As it is the responsibility of the developer to free it? If not, at which point the freeing of memory will happen?

Comment: On modern systems it remains marked as used until the application exits.

Comment: The responsibility of the developer to handle memory is one of the more difficult aspects of C++.

Comment: @ColinvH I disagree. Maybe in legacy C++ or "C with Classes" mentality, yes. But with Modern C++ coding principles and idioms, it certainly is trivial now. RAII and smart pointers make it a wonderful control experience.

Answer (score 2):

During program run yes that memory would be unavailable to you.

All memory would be freed up when your application exits.

Comment: "freed up" might be a bit of a misnomer. It's technically up to the OS how it deals with memory pages and what is actually "free". The grammar Nazi response would be "those pages are no longer in use". However you provide a practical answer so +1!

Answer (score 1):

Memory that is allocated by your app's process will be tied up until the process terminates. Android [terminates SDK apps' processes](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle) from time to time, to free up system RAM for other processes. This will only occur while your process is in the background (e.g., user presses HOME).